# AttributeError when attempting to use imported module

Tags: python, python-import, attributeerror

#in Sum.py module

```
       def sum(a,b):
           c=a+b
           print("ans=",c)
```

#in main.py module

```
       import Sum
       Sum.sum(1,2)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-15-d8f21a3fe455> in <module>
  ----> 1 Sum.sum(1,2)

 AttributeError: module 'Sum' has no attribute 'sum'
```

I'm getting attribute errors. What does this mean? Is there any problem in my code.

Comment: What is the output of `print(Sum.__file__)` (place it after the import line)? Is it the same as your Sum.py?

Comment: @GinoMempin   the output is  C:\Users\tirum\Sum.py which means the module is found. But the problem here is it can't find attribute sum. What might be the reason?

Comment: How did you define `sum` function? Is it declared module-wide / global in Sum.py? Because the indentation of the `sum` code seems to indicate it's part of something else, part of a class or a function? In that case you cannot access it with just `Sum.sum`.

Comment: [I cannot reproduce your issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sbis0.png). You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: @GinoMempin I declared it globally & The code in module  Sum.py is just some def function to add two numbers and I have to import it to another program. So I used the import keyword but I'm not understanding why the "sum" function is not being found. (I'm using Jupiter notebook)

Comment: "*(I'm using Jupiter notebook)*" You really should [edit] to put as much as relevant detail as possible, for people to reproduce your issue. If you are on Jupyter notebook, then make sure to re-run any cells that loads/imports Sum.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure, here the `Sum` is a file name and not a class(so no attribute). Moreover, you are using a defined function within the file `Sum.py`.

Provided all your files are in the same folder:

```
folder_1:
|--main.py
|--Sum.py
```

In your `main.py`, you have to import it the following way:

```
from Sum import sum
sum(1,2)
```

If the folder structure is of the following order:

```
-main.py
-folder_1
 |---Sum.py
```

It can be done by specifying the empty `__init__.py` file in the folder containing the `Sum.py` file.

which would look like this:

```
-main.py
-folder_1
 |---Sum.py
 |---__init__.py
```

And your import should be like below in the `main.py`:

```
from folder_1.Sum import sum
sum(1,2)
```

Comment: `import Sum` and `Sum.sum(1,2)` should also work. There's probably something wrong on the OP's env that the imported `Sum` is not the same Sum.py.